# Erro ao instalar/atualizar pacote com composer

Tags: php, composer

Estou fazendo a instalação/Atualização do pacote usando o composer, mas esta aparecendo essa erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

composer.json

```
{
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "8.0.2"
  }
}
```

O que devo fazer para corrigir o erro?

Comment: Tenta atualizar não definindo a versão do mpdf.  

 "mpdf/mpdf": "*"

Comment: @Vinícius Esta pedindo para instalar essa extensão `gd`

Answer (score 1):

Para quem tiver o mesmo problema.

Basta ir no arquivo `php.ini` localizar a linha `;extension=gd2` e remover o `;` que esta no inicio do arquivo.

Pronto!

Answer (score -2):

Olá @Tiago, não sei se já resolveu esse problema mas tente colocar a versão que o próprio composer sugere: **v8.0.2**.
Contudo, o techo do seu arquivo **composer.json** ficaria assim:

```
{
  "require": {
    "phpmailer/phpmailer": "~6.0",
    "mpdf/mpdf": "v8.0.2"
  }
}
```